# How to apply TextColumns method to split one column into two in part of a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to select an area in a Word document that contains several paragraphs to split them from one column into two.

```vb
Public Sub testSplitColumn()
    Dim targetDoc As Document
    Dim sourceFileName As String
    
    sourceFileName = "file path"
    Set targetDoc = Documents.Open(sourceFileName, , True)
    targetDoc.Paragraphs(503).range.Select

    'Splitting column on word
    With targetDoc.Paragraphs(503).range.PageSetup.TextColumns
        .SetCount NumColumns:=2
        .EvenlySpaced = True
        .LineBetween = False
    End With
End Sub
```

It is columnizing the paragraphs in the entire document, not just the selected paragraphs.

VBA code that can achieve the correct effect through Word macro recording:

```vb
Sub split()
    If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
        ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
    End If
    If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type <> wdPrintView Then
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
    End If
    With Selection.PageSetup.TextColumns
        .SetCount NumColumns:=2
        .EvenlySpaced = True
        .LineBetween = False
    End With
End Sub
```

How can I fix my VBA code?

Comment: When you do it manually Word adds a continuous section break at the end of the text that is columnized.  Maybe you need to do that same thing in your VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JerryJeremiah said: you need section breaks before and after your selection.
When recording a macro - they will be inserted as well.

I would create a generic sub to insert the section breaks:

```vb
Public Sub test_splitTo2Columns()

'your original code
Dim targetDoc As Document
Dim sourceFileName As String

sourceFileName = "file path"
Set targetDoc = Documents.Open(sourceFileName, , True)

'calling the generic function to test with specific paragraph
splitTo2Columns targetDoc.Paragraphs(503).Range

'this will work too - splitting the selected range
splitTo2Columns ActiveDocument.Selection.Range

End Sub


Public Sub splitTo2Columns(rg As Range, Optional fSplitWholeParagraphs As Boolean = True)

Dim rgToSplit As Range
Set rgToSplit = rg.Duplicate

If fSplitWholeParagraphs = True Then
    'in case rg = selection and selection is only a single character
    rgToSplit.Start = rgToSplit.Paragraphs.First.Range.Start
    rgToSplit.End = rgToSplit.Paragraphs.Last.Range.End
End If

insertSectionBreakContinous rgToSplit, wdCollapseStart
insertSectionBreakContinous rgToSplit, wdCollapseEnd

rgToSplit.Start = rgToSplit.Start + 1   'move behind first section break
With rg.PageSetup.TextColumns
    .SetCount NumColumns:=2
    .EvenlySpaced = True
    .LineBetween = False
End With

End Sub

Private Sub insertSectionBreakContinous(rg As Range, startEnd As WdCollapseDirection)
Dim rgBreak As Range
Set rgBreak = rg.Duplicate
With rgBreak
    .Collapse startEnd
    .InsertBreak wdSectionBreakContinuous
End With
End Sub
```